# Names combined by dot automatically when assign value of a named array with a named variable

Tags: r, named

A simple example:

```
a <- quantile(1:10, 0.1)
a
```

output:

```
10%
1.9
```

Use a to assign value of a named array:

```
b = c(index=0, value=a)
b
```

output:

```
index value.10%
 0.0     1.9
```

Why the 'value' and '10%' are combined by dot automatically?
How to avoid this, as I just want to name it as 'value'?

Comment: You can use `unname`: `c(index=0, value=unname(a))` or `as.vector`: `c(index=0, value=as.vector(a))`. From the help file `?c`: *`c` is sometimes used for its side effect of removing attributes except names, for example to turn an array into a vector. `as.vector` is a more intuitive way to do this, but also drops names.*

Comment: or `c(index=0, setNames(a,"value"))` or `setNames(c(0,a),c("index","value"))`

Comment: @Imo, this solves my problem. Thank you!

Comment: In this specific case, you can also call `quantile` with the `names=FALSE` argument, since you want to override them: `a <- quantile(1:10, 0.1,names=FALSE)`. This way you get also an efficiency bonus.

Answer (score 3):

The `b` object created in the question is an R named vector, not an R array.

### array

An R array is an R vector with a dimension (or dimensions) and possibly a `dimnames` attribute.  It is created like this:

```
ar <- array(c(0, a), dimnames = list(c("index", "value"))); ar
## index value 
##   0.0   1.9
```

### named vector

To create a named vector with specified names  rather than creating an array use setNames to overwrite any existing names:

```
v <- setNames(c(0, a), c("index", "value")); v
## index value 
##   0.0   1.9
```

or use `names<-` like this:

```
v <- c(0, a)
names(v) <- c("index", "value")
```

or as mentioned in the comments already, create `b` from `unname(a)` rather than from `a` to avoid the combined names.

### attributes

Note that the attributes of `ar` are:

```
attributes(ar)
## List of 2
##  $ dim     : int 2
##  $ dimnames:List of 1
##   ..$ : chr [1:2] "index" "value"
```

and the attributes of `v` are:

```
attributes(v)
## $names
## [1] "index" "value"
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers in comment help you for this problem but I think that you have to understand the fact that `a` is already a named vector. So using `c` (`c` for `concat`) here you try to concat two objects not of the same type. That's why R tries to make it work by concatenating names, here the the orignal one (`10%`) and the one you want to give.

In this context it would make more sense to me to write `c(c(index=0), a)` and then to change names, or `c(index=0, value=unname(a))`